# 1с: выбрать подразделение

Tags: 1с

Делаю запрос:

```
ЗапросПодразделения = Новый Запрос;

ЗапросПодразделения.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
|    Подразделения.Ссылка,
|    Подразделения.Наименование
|ИЗ
|    Справочник.Подразделения КАК Подразделения
|ГДЕ
|    Подразделения.Наименование = &Наименование";

ЗапросПодразделения.УстановитьПараметр("Наименование", Пользователь);
ВыборкаП = ЗапросПодразделения.Выполнить().Выбрать();
ВыборкаП.Следующий();
Сообщить(ВыборкаП.Ссылка);
```

Ошибочка выходит:

```
 Таблица не найдена "Справочник.Подразделения"
```

Как еще можно получить подразделение? По партнеру например или по названию подразделения, типа "Москва"?

Comment: может быть вы хотите получить все подразделения с которыми работал ваш партнер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
               |    Подразделения.Ссылка,
               |    Подразделения.Наименование
               |ИЗ
               |    Справочник.Подразделения КАК Подразделения
               |ГДЕ
               |    Подразделения.Ссылка = &Ссылка";
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Подразделение);

Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();
Выборка.Следующий();

Наименование = Выборка.Наименование;

Сообщение = Новый СообщениеПользователю;
Сообщение.Текст = Наименование;
Сообщение.Сообщить();
```

После ключевого слова ИЗ вы указываете таблицу к которой необходимо обратиться. Например Справочник.Контрагенты, при этом справочник должен существовать в вашей конфигурации. При установке отбора в запросе нужно указывать ссылку (тип ссылка), а не наименование (тип текст). Если необходимо найти все элементы с похожими наименованиями воспользуйтесь конструкцией [ПОДОБНО](http://help1c.com/faq/view/852.html)

**UPD:**

Не совсем понятно для чего вы хотите получить подразделения и главное откуда?

Небольшой пример получения данных. У нас есть справочник контрагенты, у него есть подчиненный справочник ДоговораКонтрагентов. Нам необходимо получить все договора по котрагенту Петров тогда запрос будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
//
    ВЫБРАТЬ
        ДоговорыКонтрагентов.Ссылка
    ИЗ
        Справочник.ДоговорыКонтрагентов КАК ДоговорыКонтрагентов
    ГДЕ
        ДоговорыКонтрагентов.Владелец = &Владелец

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Владелец", КонтрагентПетров);
//
```

[image]

Comment: Ну как выбирать я понял, спасибо. Вопрос был как получить подразделения. Какая конфигурация - даже не знаю, только версия известна - 8.2.

Comment: 8.2 - это версия платформы

Comment: @Егор Соколов по UPD: я уже понял, как составляются запросы и прочие плюшки. Я просто не пойму, почему таблицы "Справочник.Подразделения" не существует и какая вместо неё таблица. Поиск молчит как партизан.

Comment: Откройте дерево метаданных, посморите какие у вас есть справочники. Либо если у вас есть реквизит, который вы предполагаете как подразделение, то посмотрите его тип

Comment: @Егор Соколов хм, у меня нет этого справочника. Обидно. Ну ладно, сказали пока забить на это. Спасибо, в будущем вернутся, конечно, придется.